# Add and Replace placeholder in XML from property files

Tags: java, xml, properties

I am developing a web application which will be deployed in different environments like Dev, Test and Production. Some of the configurations will be specific to environments and so I need to change the configurations in the property files with respect to the environments where the project is deployed.

I added the Environment variable in machine and obtained it using the method

> System.getEnv("Environment")

which would return the value like, dev, test and prod and I load the respective property files (File names are dev-config.properties, test-config.properties).

I am implementing the PicketLink libraries in jBoss AS to integrate the application with SSO-SAML. One of the configurations is to add a file named picketlink-idfed.xml, where I mention the IDP URL and application url. Both the URLs will be different for environments. I cannot have different file names like dev-picketlink-idfed.xml and so I cannot follow the above approach of using different files.

Question is that I need to use the same file picketlink-idfed.xml, just by adding the placeholder and replace it with the respective values from the property files. Attached the sample content of picketlink-idfed.xml.

```
<IdentityURL>https://idfed.test.com.au/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx?LoginToRP=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.test.com.au%2Fdisplays%2FHome.action
</IdentityURL>
<ServiceURL>https://app.test.com.au/displays/Home.action
</ServiceURL>
```

In the above line the values for tags **IdentityURL** and **ServiceURL** will be changed for different environments. Can you please tell me on how to address this issue?

Note: For time being, I am replacing the contents for every deployment, which is not good practice. Also, I am not using Maven or Ant build files. I cannot use these due to insufficient time.

Comment: If you can't use maven or ant, then it get tricky. Create different env files and programmatically use them in your code . why don't you use properties file  ?  Is this XML related to some API ?

Comment: @Utkarsh: Do you mean to create 3 different picketlink-idfed.xml files? If yes, then I cannot create as JBoss will not recognize the files if they have different name. BTW, how do you deal with Maven if I use it in future?

Comment: Maven is very simple to use and its worth spending 15 min on it and you could achieve your goal very easily. Check this : https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html . You can create different maven profiles in pom.xml and you can set  your properties value based on maven profile. Use can use properties inside placeholders